# ReactJS Redux variable not being updated properly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I verified the dispatch is going through properly with redux devtools, and verified the value is being set properly.

The problem is when FetchUpdateList() is run, it is using the old state value of the updateLog store variable.

Here is my store variable:
`var updateLog = useSelector((state) => state.updateLog.value);`

My checkbox triggering the function:
`<Checkbox checked={checkBoxActive} onChange={HandleCheckBox} />`

```
function HandleCheckBox(event) {
        dispatch(setUpdateLog({ 'start': 0, 'end': 10, 'viewOneUser': !updateLog.viewOneUser }))
        console.log("...Running HandleCheckBox()...")
        console.log(event.target.checked);
        setLoadingMore(true);
        setCheckBoxActive(event.target.checked);
        ResetValues();
        setTimeout(() => FetchUpdateList(), 2000);
    }

    function ResetValues() {
        console.log("...Running ResetValues()...")
        setUpdateList([]);
        setMoreEnabled(true);
    }
```

Here is redux devtools showing the action and current value:
[image]
[image]

And here is the value after FetchUpdateList() runs:
[image]

Here is the function where the store variable is being read as the old value:

```
async function FetchUpdateList() {
        setLoadingMore(true);
        console.log(updateLog);
        if (updateLog.viewOneUser) {
            var call = await GetUpdateListAPI(props.instance, props.accounts, updateLog.start, updateLog.end, null, profileData.user == "" ? localStorage.getItem('user') : profileData.user);
        } else {
            var call = await GetUpdateListAPI(props.instance, props.accounts, updateLog.start, updateLog.end, null, null);
        }
        if (call.Success) {
            var list = [];
            setUpdatesLength(call.Length);
            dispatch(setUpdateLog({ 'start': updateLog.start + 10, 'end': updateLog.end + 10, 'viewOneUser': updateLog.viewOneUser }))
```

Here is where I setup my redux store:

```
const updateLogSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'updateLog',
    initialState: {
      value: {'start': 0, 'end': 10, 'viewOneUser': false},
    },
    reducers: {
      setUpdateLog: (state, action) => {
        state.value = action.payload
      },
      
    },
  })
```

```
export const { setUpdateLog } = updateLogSlice.actions
```

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ...,
    updateLog: updateLogSlice.reducer,
  },
})
```

Comment: *it is using the old state value of the updateLog store variable.* Do you mean `updateLog` is using the initializing value from this one `initialState: {  value: {'start': 0, 'end': 10, 'viewOneUser': false},
    },`?

Answer (score 0):

`FetchUpdateList` is called from a closure over the `updateLog` state from the `HandleCheckBox` function. If `FetchUpdateList` needs to access the current state value then a trivial solution is to import the `store` and access state via `store.getState` method.

Example:

```js
import store from '.../path/to/store';

...

async function FetchUpdateList() {
  setLoadingMore(true);

  const state = store.getState();          // <-- current state value
  const updateLog = state.updateLog.value; // <-- current updateLog value

  console.log(updateLog);

  if (updateLog.viewOneUser) {
    var call = await GetUpdateListAPI(
      props.instance,
      props.accounts,
      updateLog.start,
      updateLog.end,
      null,
      profileData.user == ""
        ? localStorage.getItem('user')
        : profileData.user
    );
  } else {
    var call = await GetUpdateListAPI(
      props.instance,
      props.accounts,
      updateLog.start,
      updateLog.end,
      null,
      null
    );

  }
  if (call.Success) {
    var list = [];
    setUpdatesLength(call.Length);
    store.dispatch(setUpdateLog({
      start: updateLog.start + 10,
      end: updateLog.end + 10,
      viewOneUser: updateLog.viewOneUser
    }))
  ...
```